# Select method is not validated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a select method in form and when I click on submit method without filing the form, various errors are shown which I have included in validate methods, like first name required, email required, etc.
So the problem is when I start entering the first name, the error disappears. But the same is not happening in case of select method. When I select certain options there, the error still remains saying, select at least one option. This error goes away when I click submit button. But I want this error to go away when I select at least one option, like in the case of first name when I start typing, the error goes away.

I have included my validation methods in $(document).ready(function()

Any help will be appreciated.

The following is the code snippet:

```
var newusercontainer = $('#newUsererrorcontainer');
var newuservalidator = $("#newUserForm").validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
registerUser();
},
 errorContainer: newusercontainer,
        errorLabelContainer: $("ul", newusercontainer),
        wrapper: 'li',
        meta: "validate",
        rules: {
newUserFirstName: {
            required:true,
            maxlength:50,
        },


        sector: {
                    required: true,
        },

    },
messages: {
        newUserFirstName: {
            required: "The First name field is required.",
            maxlength: "Please enter with in 60 characters"

        },

        sector: {
            required: "The Sector field is required.",

        },



    }
    });
```

Comment: Can u provide the code or create jsfiddle .

Comment: do the validation of every element in `.onblur()` function